# Trying to convert a part of WebApp to Android native

Tags: android, web-applications

I have a webapp whose front end is in Javascript and HTML and back end in Asp.net. Can anyone tell me how do I embed native Android to a part of WebApp ?

Comment: you mean creating an Android App that accesses the your backend Asp.net ?

Comment: I already have  webApp whose backend is in Asp.Net and front end is in JS and HTML. I have to convert a part of it to Android native code.

Comment: that's what i am asking, which part you want to convert ? front end or backend ? i am sure front end one, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call javascript by calling loadUrl() on the WebView.  For example: `webview.loadUrl("javascript: doSomethingInJavascript();");`

You can setup a Javascript Interface that will let you call native Java methods from javascript. For more about that see this Android doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Also, if you meant that you want to embed native Android view's into a webpage. The WebView is a AbsoluteLayout and you can add views to it with addView.